# Why does XCode keep downloading old deleted profiles and duplicates of the same profile?

Tags: ios, xcode

ingIf I refresh the profiles in XCode it:

a) Pulls down ones that no longer exist. Profiles that have been deleted from the portal and are no longer there

b) Pulls down multiple copies of the same profile. If I add a new device and then update the profiles to include that new device. Then XCode will pull down the new updated profile but also the same profile with an older date (even though the portal only shows one, the latest).

If I delete them them XCode they re-appear.

I'm having problems getting push notifications to work with an ad-hoc distrubtion and so want to ensure I am build with the latest profiles.
This behaviour of XCode is irritating at least, and possibly the source of my problems at worst.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to revoke the matching developer certificates in the portal and delete them from your keychain. For me, that was the only way to resolve this problem...